# Jenkins Groovy, Jenkins DSL Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to change the jenkins job status Manually in pipeline?

Example:-

I have 7 freestyle jobs (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) in Pipeline, job A initial job, after A, we have three parallel test jobs (B,C,D). Job E is the report generation job, here we need to implement user interaction for Pipeline will continue or not?.

Conditions at Job E:
1) If Job E is successful, Pipeline will continue to Release 
2) if Job E is Failed, Pipeline should be stop here.
3) if Job E is Unstable, here we need to implement user interaction. In user interaction, user need to change the Job E UNSTABLE status to either success or failure.

Eg:- If job E UNSTABLE, in user interaction. 
      user click on proceed, job E changes unstable to SUCCESS 
      user click on NO, job E changes unstable to failure.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommand trying to change status of a a build.
Your use case is perfect for pipelines. Ideally, I would recommand to get rid of the freestyle jobs and develop a proper pipeline.

If you can not, you can still orchestrate freestyle jobs from groovy pipelines.

To trigger a job from a pipeline :

```
build job: jobFullname, parameters: listOfParameters
```

[See for more options](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/).

To display a message waiting for a decision :

```
input "Continue or abort pipeline ?"
```

[See for more options](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/).

If you still want to change build status, you first need to find the job :

```
Job job = (Job) Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobFullname)
```

Then find the run you want to change :

```
Run run = job.getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)
```

or more conveniently, get the full list and loop in it to find the one you want :

```
RunList<RunT> runs = job.getBuilds()
```

Then, once you have the run you are looking for :

```
run.setResult(Result.SUCCESS)
run.setResult(Result.FAILURE)
```

Comment: Thank you, Please give the full script for above pipeline

Comment: You have all the element to write the script yourself. Give it a try and ask another question if you are stuck on another point that is not documented yet. In the mean time, please accept or upvote my answer if you find it satisfying.